# R - Unable to deploy application on shinyapps.io because of expired token

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, token, shinyapps

Since yesterday evening I could easily deploy and update my shiny application on shinyapps.io. Today I made few changes, tried to deploy again, and I am getting the following error which I don't know what it refers to:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 1099846...DONE
Deploying bundle: 6170071 for application: 1099846 ...
Waiting for task: 1198780170
  error: Processing bundle: 6170071
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1198780173 error: Unhandled Exception: An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Token expired: current date/time 1659692079 must be before the expiration date/time16596
Execution halted
```

I tried to create a new token on shinyapps.io for the rsconnect package, but it doesn't work. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks

**UPDATE**: I tried to re-deploy it one time and it worked, then I tried again and it's not working again.
I also went on the shinyapps.io website, and tried to delete an old application, and I got the same error. Does it means they're having problems on their side?

[image]

Comment: Same issue here, only since last night

Comment: Got an answer from the RStudio team, they're working to solve the problem: https://status.rstudio.com/history

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. I went on to my Shinyapps dashboard and re-copied across the token and secret from there to our GitHub repo settings. Re-deployed and all went well.

Comment: The team solved the problem